# Changing from indirect to direct speech

Tags: indirect-speech, narration

**Change into Direct speech:**

- He said that he had started a job.
- **Two possibilities:**

1. He said, "I have started a job".
2. He said, "I started a job".

- Which of the above is correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

He said, "I have started a job." Or
He said, "I started a job."

Both are correct because both present perfect and past simple tense are changed into past perfect tense in indirect speech.